# Moving linux files based on date in python

Tags: python, linux

In Linux I want to copy, rename and move files based on a specific date.. exp.

```
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 10484224 Nov 22 14:41 HELLO.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 10484224 Oct 22 14:42 HI.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 10484224 Dec 22 14:42 GOOD.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 10484224 Mar 22 14:43 DAY.dbf
```

There would be 1000's of these files, with different days and years.Is there a way to get the file and based on that date send it to a directory.. I want to be able to create a program that will take a number of days and "sort" the files according to month and year using the modification time.

I want to do this in python.

Comment: As a place to start, you probably want to have a look at the [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) call and the `st_mtime` property it gives you for the last modification time of the file. To help more, we'd need to see what you've tried and what's not working.

Comment: I know you say you want to do it in python, but have you considered shell scripting? It'll tend to be a lot faster than python. Also, could you explain what you mean by "sort the files" a bit more? Rearrange their order in the directory according to date?

Comment: Yes so basically I want all the Jan 2015 files in 2015/jan folder. Its all apart of a python script

Comment: You do understand that the time stamps you see are just the last modified date, right? These files might have been created almost entirely on different days, then tweaked a little months later. The modification time is not a very useful means of organizing files.

Comment: It is because some of the files have not been modified in years and those are the ones that I want to move.